# Re-Writing to java txt files

Tags: java, formatter

i was wondering if there was a way to add to text files already created. because when i do this on an already created file:

```
public Formatter f = new Formatter("filename.txt");
```

it re-writes the current filename.txt with a blank one.
thanks, Quinn

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the constructor with an `OutputStream` argument instead of a `File` argument. That way you can open an OutputStream in append mode and do your formatting on that. [Link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter%28java.io.OutputStream%29)

Comment: This would work but given that the OP used "filename.txt" in the question it would be better to construct the Formatter with a `FileWriter` instead, as it implements `Appendable`.  I don't like using `OutputStream`s for writing text; that is what `Writer`s are for.  Of course you can pass a character encoding to the `OutputStream` version but IMHO the writer approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the constructor for `Formatter` which takes an `Appendable` as an argument.

There are several classes which implement the `Appendable` interface. The most convenient, in your case, should be `FileWriter`.

This [FileWrite constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) will let you open a file (whose name is specified as a String), in append mode.

Comment: Just to be clear: `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);`  `Formatter f = new Formatter (fw);`

Answer (score 1):

Use `FileOutputStream` with append boolean value as true eg `new FileOutputStream("C:/concat.txt", true));`

### Example

```
public class FileCOncatenation {

        static public void main(String arg[]) throws java.io.IOException {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/concat.txt", true));

                File file2 = new File("C:/Text/file2.rxt");
                                       System.out.println("Processing " + file2.getPath() + "... ");
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2
                                        .getPath()));
                        String line = br.readLine();
                        while (line != null) {
                                pw.println(line);
                                line = br.readLine();
                        }
                        br.close();
//                }
                pw.close();
                System.out.println("All files have been concatenated into concat.txt");
        }
}
```